# Why nodejs's require is not accessible in this closure using debugger console? Possible v8 optimisation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, v8

Here is copypasted code from node-inspector. I try to use require in debugger console to get some module for debugging purposes but it is not defined. Can anyone explain me why does it happen?

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 'use strict';

var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request-promise');
var Q = require('q');


module.exports = {
  compile: function compile(options){
    //require is no longer available at this point
    return {
      getData: function getData(callback){
        request(options.uri)
          .then(function(response){
            //here I need require
            var $ = cheerio.load(response);
            var result = $(options.selector).text().trim();
            callback(undefined, result);
          })
          .catch(function(error){
            callback(error);
          });
      }
    };
  }
};
});
```

UPDATE:
Further investigation showed that if I actually add something like "var fs = require('fs')" at specified lines instead of trying to invoke it in node-debugger console - it works. Is it possible that there is some v8 optimisation going on that I am not aware of?

Comment: How are you trying to use `require()` within of `compile(options)`? Your post doesn't appear to provide that detail. Do any errors occur?

Comment: require variable is just simply undefined at specified lines.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited info provided I am venturing a guess.

You have defined an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and not called it. You have to call an IIFE to execute it.

```
(function())()
```

**Also at the time of calling you must pass the dependencies (arguments).**

Example for clarity (using node REPL):

```
> (function(a) { return a  } )
[Function]
> (function(a) { return a  } )(5) // call with value of argument "a"
5
```

In your case it would look like

```
;(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
 "use strict"

  var cheerio = require("cheerio")
  var request = require("request-promise")
  var Q = require("q")

  module.exports = {
    compile: function compile(options) {
    //require is no longer available at this point
    return {
      getData: function getData(callback) {
        request(options.uri)
          .then(function(response) {
            //here I need require
            var $ = cheerio.load(response)
            var result = $(options.selector)
              .text()
              .trim()
            callback(undefined, result)
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            callback(error)
          })
      }
    }
  }
}
})(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) // pass arguments when calling IIFE
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!